# Subclass of QGraphicsLayoutItem and QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: qt

I want to create grid layout with text items and I want this layout to be updated after added text to text item, but this not work.
Here is fragment of my source code:

```
MyItem::MyItem(const QString &text, QGraphicsLayout* layout, QGraphicsItem *parent):
    QGraphicsLayoutItem(),
    QGraphicsTextItem(parent),
    mLayout(layout)
{
    setGraphicsItem(this);

    setHtml(text);

    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
}

void MyItem::setGeometry(const QRectF &geom)
{
    prepareGeometryChange();
    QGraphicsLayoutItem::setGeometry(geom);
    setPos(geom.topLeft());
}

QSizeF MyItem::sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which, const QSizeF &constraint) const
{
    return boundingRect().size();
}

void MyItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && textInteractionFlags() == Qt::NoTextInteraction) {
        setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextEditorInteraction);
    }

    QGraphicsTextItem::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void MyItem::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::NoTextInteraction);
    auto cursor = textCursor();
    cursor.clearSelection();
    setTextCursor(cursor);
    QGraphicsTextItem::focusOutEvent(event);
}

void MyItem::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    QGraphicsTextItem::keyPressEvent(event);

    qDebug() << boundingRect();

    updateGeometry();
    mLayout->activate();
}
```

Result is that when i add text to text item and his width is growing the next cell is not moving to make a place for first cell:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    auto scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    auto layout = new QGraphicsGridLayout;

    auto t1 = new MyItem("cell1", layout);
    layout->addItem(t1, 0, 0);
    auto t2 = new MyItem("cell2", layout);
    layout->addItem(t2, 0, 1);

    auto container = new QGraphicsWidget;
    container->setLayout(layout);
    scene->addItem(container);

    auto view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(800, 600);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `mLayout->updateGeometry();` in `void MyItem::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)` method solved my problem.